# How to return zeros in months not in the database

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am trying to return the number of people registered in a particular month, but would like also to return zeros in months that are not in the database.

The following query returns number of people registered in months in the database:

```
select 
    extract(year from "DATECREATED") as YEAR, 
    extract(month from "DATECREATED") as mon,
    count("USERID") as Total
from 
    TBLG2O_USEROFO 
where 
    extract(year from "DATECREATED") = '2014'
group by 
    extract(year from "DATECREATED"), 
    extract(month from "DATECREATED")
order by 
    1, 2
```

Comment: you didnt specify a DBMS...

Comment: BTW your `WHERE` clause can just be things like `YEAR='2014' etc; thats the whole point of aliasing in the `SELECT` portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, to do this, you need a second table that just contains the month number per row.

Assuming you create a table called `MONTHS` with a single column, `MONTH_NUMBER`, you could use this query to create the output you're looking for - it will count the number of rows per month for the year you specify and show zeros for any month with no rows.

Note, this query also has a downside - it will only work over a calendar year, so you wouldn't be able to split it across years (say, July 2013 - June 2014).

```
SELECT COALESCE(YEAR, 2014) AS YEAR,
       MONTHS.MONTH_NUMBER  AS MONTH,
       COALESCE(TOTAL, 0)   AS "MONTH COUNT"
  FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATECREATED) AS YEAR,
               EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATECREATED) AS MONTH,
               COUNT(DATECREATED) AS TOTAL
          FROM TBLG2O_USEROFO            
         WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATECREATED) = '2014'
         GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATECREATED), 
                  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATECREATED)) LFT
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN MONTHS
               ON MONTH_NUMBER = LFT.MONTH
 ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH
```

[See this query in action at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93f6a/1).

Essentially, this is the Oracle version of [@Eran's MySQL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736456/42471).

Comment: the problem is am not able to create another table in that database

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on mysql so you might require some tinkering for oracle.

First create a table with the months of the year...

```
create table months(month int);
insert into months values(1);
insert into months values(2);
insert into months values(3);
insert into months values(4);
insert into months values(5);
insert into months values(6);
insert into months values(7);
insert into months values(8);
insert into months values(9);
insert into months values(10);
insert into months values(11);
insert into months values(12);
```

The use a right join with the months table to achieve desired effect:

```
select coalesce(YEAR, 2014) year, m.month, coalesce(Total, 0) as total 
from 
  (select year(DATECREATED) as YEAR, month(c. DATECREATED) month, count("DATECREATED") as Total 
  from comments c
  where year(DATECREATED) ='2014'
  group by year, month(c.date_sent)) as c
right join months m
on c.month = m.month
order by year, month
```

If you cannot add a temporary table, here's a way around it:

```
select coalesce(YEAR, 2014) year, m.month, coalesce(Total, 0) as total 
from 
  (select year(DATECREATED) as YEAR, month(c. DATECREATED) month, count("DATECREATED") as Total 
  from comments c
  where year(DATECREATED) ='2014'
  group by year, month(c.date_sent)) as c
right join
  (select 1 as month union select 2 as month union select 3 as month 
   union select 4  as month union select 5 as month union select 6 as month 
   union select 7 as month union select 8 as month union select 9 as month 
   union select 10 as month union select 11 as month union select 12 as month) m
on c.month = m.month
order by year, month
```

Comment: Can you create a temporary table?

Comment: [Err] ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended   am using oracle database

Comment: Sorry, am not familiar enough with oracle to debug that.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle when you need to "synthesize" rows which are not directly present in the database you can use *modeling clause*. [model keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/sqlmodel.htm)

I used Jared's SQL Fiddle to produce even simpler example, without any 2nd table:

```
select * from
(
  select count(1) cnt, trunc(datecreated, 'MONTH') dt
  from TBLG2O_USEROFO
  group by trunc(datecreated, 'MONTH')
)
model
--partition by (department)
dimension by (dt)
measures (cnt, cast (null as number) tech_cnt)
rules sequential order(
    tech_cnt[ for dt from to_date('2013-01-01','RRRR-MM-DD') 
                       to to_date('2014-12-31','RRRR-MM-DD') 
                increment NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH')] 
    = nvl(cnt[cv(dt)], 0)
)
order by dt;
```

Imagine the result of the query being an Excel sheet. Then the assignment `tech_cnt[dt] = nvl(cnt[cv(dt), 0)` is an "excel macro".

Comment: something like this would be fine but ,would prefer to exclude column cnt and show only month in the dt column